# Proper way to use database on Xamarin

Tags: android, mysql, xamarin

I 've a theorical question about Xamarin and how to use MySQL databases on an App. I just need a database to store users for an app, the my question is: D I need a webservice for this? I know that is maybe the proper way to work with databases in a mobile app, but as I said, I just need to store users and allow that they can connect to the App using an account. Exist another method more simple to work with it? (I just need a table with the password, and the login).

Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, yes!  The proper way to consume an database from a mobile app is using a webservice, if building this around your MySQL database is too much for your needs then maybe ask if MySQL is the right place for your data.  There are plenty of web service